# How can I end UDP stream with FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, udp, rtsp

Im using ffmpeg for rtsp streaming. And i have 2 options - udp and tcp. I have no problem with tcp, but when its up to udp, even when i click on "disconnect" - it still running.

My code:

```
m_inputFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
m_options = nullptr;
m_videoCodecContext = nullptr;
m_packet = av_packet_alloc();
m_frame = av_frame_alloc();

//av_dict_set(&m_options, "buffer_size", "2000000", 0);
av_dict_set(&m_options, "rtsp_transport", m_connectionType.c_str(), 0);

emit statusChanged(StreamStatus::Started);
m_inputFormatContext->interrupt_callback.callback = &RtspStream::interruptCallback;
m_inputFormatContext->interrupt_callback.opaque = this;

m_timeout = 20000;
m_operationStart = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
if (avformat_open_input(&m_inputFormatContext, m_url.c_str(), nullptr, &m_options) < 0)
{
    cleanUp(RtspStream::StreamStatus::Failed);
    return;
}

if (avformat_find_stream_info(m_inputFormatContext, nullptr) < 0)
{
    cleanUp(RtspStream::StreamStatus::Failed);
    return;
}

m_videoStreamIndex = -1;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_inputFormatContext->nb_streams; ++i)
{

    if (m_inputFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        m_videoStreamIndex = i;
        m_videoCodecParameters = m_inputFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar;
        break;
    }
}

if (m_videoStreamIndex == -1)
{
    cleanUp(RtspStream::StreamStatus::Failed);
    return;
}
m_codec = (AVCodec*)avcodec_find_decoder(m_videoCodecParameters->codec_id);
if (!m_codec)
{
    cleanUp(RtspStream::StreamStatus::Failed);
    return;
}

m_videoCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_codec);

avcodec_parameters_to_context(m_videoCodecContext, m_videoCodecParameters);

if (avcodec_open2(m_videoCodecContext, m_codec, nullptr) < 0)
{
    cleanUp(RtspStream::StreamStatus::Failed);
    return;
}
```

that is Init

```
av_frame_free(&m_frameRGB);
av_frame_free(&m_frame);
av_packet_free(&m_packet);
av_dict_free(&m_options);
avcodec_close(m_videoCodecContext);
avcodec_free_context(&m_videoCodecContext);
avformat_close_input(&m_inputFormatContext);
```

that is disconnect

I`ve tried a lot of possible "options" for ffmpeg, but none of them solve my issue.